# Pickling and loading a pandas dataframe with each loop to save progress ...bad idea?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a for loop that does an API call over thousands of rows.

(I know for loops are not recommended but this api is rate limited so slow is better. I know I can also do `iterrows` but this is just an example)

Sometimes I come back to find the loop has failed or there's something wrong with the api and I need to stop the loop. This means I lose all my data.

I was thinking of pickling the dataframe at the end of each loop, and re-loading it at the start. This would save all updates made to the dataframe.

Fake example (not working code - this is just a `'what if'`):

```
for i in range(len(df1)):

    # check if df pickle file in directory

    if pickle in directory:

        # load file
        df1 = pickle.load(df1)

        # append new data
        df1.loc[i,'api_result'] = requests(http/api/call/data/)

        # dump it to file
        pickle.dump(df1)

    else:
         # start of loop

         # append new data
         df1.loc[i,'api_result'] = requests(http/api/call/data/)

         # dump to file
         pickle.dump(df1)
```

And if this is **not** a good way to keep the updated file in case of failure or early stoppage, what is?

Comment: I would think [`HDF5`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-hdf5) is better suited since you can append.

Comment: At this point would be better to write back the dataframe from the place you read from at each iteration, instead of serializing it

Comment: Hard to say but wouldn't it be better segregate the api request so that if it fails or *hangs*, you can recover without losing anything?

Comment: @Nikaidoh what exactly do you mean? Could you explain a bit more? what do you mean write back the dataframe? Could you do a fake example in an answer perhaps?

Comment: @wwii how can I segregate the api request from the dataframe. It actually depends on data from the dataframe. I guess I should have made that clearer. Data from each row will go into the http request.

Comment: ? Put the request in a function that has a timeout or error checking , maybe throws an Exception if something goes wrong. Maybe a thread instead of a function?

Comment: @wwii that's what I did. Timeouts and exception checking. I would come back and there's 100 lines of error printouts. I would have to stop the script, and all data is lost. I haven't used threads before. Will check them out.

Comment: Can't you [Catch the Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and handle them?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good solution would be to save in append all the updates in a file

```
with open("updates.txt", "a") as f_o:
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        # append new data
        f_o.write(requests(http/api/call/data/)+"\n")
```

And if all the rows are present in the file, you can do a bulk update. If not, restart the updates from the last failed record

Comment: no @juanpa.arrivillaga, he is serializing all the dataframe at each time at each iteration, which is computational expensive

Comment: So I will have a text file with all the api results. But should I save the index of the row also? So I know exactly where to update the original dataframe.

Comment: It is irrelevant. Because the lines themself have this info. If your script stops to write at line 322, your last index is 322, for example

Comment: Sorry, I asked you a question at the top of the page also, didn't know you already answered.